# How much can I quote a book?

Tags: discussion, support

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39078908/3850595) a while ago. Today, reading Effective Java from Joshua Bloch I realized `Item 4` is speaking about this topic, adding some interesting points.

I added the info to the answer, but copy-pasting from the book a question come to my mind:

- Can I add **any** content of the book?
- If yes, how much can I add to the answer?

---

**UPDATE1**

I took a look to the copyright part of the book:

> All rights reserved. Printed in the United States of America. This publication is protected by copyright, and **permission
>   must be obtained from the publisher prior to any prohibited reproduction**, storage in a retrieval system, or transmission
>   in any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical, photocopying, recording, or likewise. For information
>   regarding permissions, write to:
>   Pearson Education, Inc.

It seems some situations can be ok to quote with permissions...

- Has SO or SE some agreement or permission?

---

**UPDATE2**

I read some fair use rules

- [Student law Australia](http://scu.edu.au/copyright/index.php/6)

  > Reproduction:
  >   In a work greater than ten pages, **one chapter or 10% of pages** [...]
  >
  > **Example**
  >   *A 60-page book may be divided into six chapters. You may copy one whole or part of a single chapter, even though the number of pages copied exceeds 10% of the total pages in the book, or you may copy six (6) pages (10% of total) from throughout the book.*

---

**UPDATE3**

- [Standford University factors of fair use](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/)

> The four factors judges consider are:
>
> - the purpose and character of your use
> - the nature of the copyrighted work
> - the amount and substantiality of the portion taken, **and**
> - the effect of the use upon the potential market.

- [Exceptions of copyright @ UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright)

> **Non-commercial research and private study**
>
> You are allowed to copy limited extracts of works when the use is non-commercial research or private study, but you must be genuinely studying (like you would if you were taking a college course). Such use is only permitted when it is ‘fair dealing’ and copying the whole work would not generally be considered fair dealing.
>
> The purpose of this exception is to allow students and researchers to make limited copies of all types of copyright works for non-commercial research or private study. In assessing whether your use of the work is permitted or not you must assess if there is any financial impact on the copyright owner because of your use. Where the impact is not significant, the use may be acceptable.
>
> If your use is for non-commercial research you must ensure that the work you reproduce is supported by a sufficient acknowledgment.

---

## OWN CONCLUSSION

As long as I only added a single item (less than a page) I think it fits quite well inside the rules, anyway, I also added [link to Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) to buy the book... hope is enough `:)`

Comment: [This](http://scu.edu.au/copyright/index.php/6) may be helpful.  Not totally general but it gives us a starting point.

Comment: You're going to have the right to quote it to an extent under fair use.  No notice in the book is going to affect that.  As far as how much of a quote is acceptable, that's not really a hard line when it comes to fair use, even though the amount of content quoted is one of the metrics used by fair use.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the query looks pretty opinion based to me; that you feel the need to quote someone just to have them share their personal opinion is of course a red flag for that.

Comment: Side note: I think you should not have *answered* that question, but instead find duplicate that talks about "how to implement singleton in Java"... Than you'd not need to search for random quotes.

Comment: Note that the bit about "10% or one chapter" is not a "fair use" rule in the sense that the phrase is used in the United States (or a "fair dealing" rule, as it is called elsewhere) -- it is a rule that very specifically applies only to academic institutions in Australia.

Comment: @apsillers I am really far away of this point less than a page from 300+, you think I quoted too much?

Comment: No, I'm just pointing out that this 10% rule is a specific license enacted in Australian law for the benefit of academic institutions only. As Stack Exchange isn't an academic institution, it doesn't really matter how close or far you are from this guideline. What *does* matter (as already answered below) is how well your use falls in line with fair use/fair dealing factors, which generally don't outline specific sizes of use. I merely wanted to minimize confusion between academic license guidelines vs fair use/dealing, since you linked to the academic guidelines with the link text "fair use".

Comment: @apsi nice point. do you have some link to the guides that apply here? Or is just our own sense?

Comment: For example, U.S. law has [four specific fair use factors](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/) used by the court to determine a use is defensible under fair use (amount/substantiality of the work used, purpose/character of use, economic impact, and type of work being used). The UK similarly has [specific guidelines about what kinds of uses](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright) are acceptable, but I'm not familiar with them personally. I imagine most jurisdictions that take copyright seriously have something similar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

TL;DR: Follow the usual protocols of quoting, attributing, and linking if possible, and you'll be fine.

In terms of Stack Overflow's policies, the only thing we're really concerned about is plagiarism, or the appearance of it. To make it clear that you're not a plagiarist:

- put the relevant section in a blockquote (`>` in markdown syntax)
- attribute the original work and author: provide names, and (legitimate) links if possible

On the legal side of things, you should be fine. I am by no means a lawyer and I do not pretend to dispense legal advice, but the doctrine of fair use should protect you. Essentially, it states that you can reuse minor sections of a work for various purposes (personal, educational, parody, etc) without breaching copyright regulations, and without seeking specific permission. So, while neither you nor SE has any agreement or explicit permission, you don't need it to quote small bits of work.

Comment: great, was what I've done, fair use says a chapter, so put a single item won't be a great deal, anyway, I also added link to amazon to buy the book, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

> As long as I only added a single item (less than a page) I think it fits quite well inside the rules, ,...

I disagree strongly with your conclusion. Even adding less than a page (a single item) may be a violation of the copyright of this book.

As you correctly found out by looking into the book:

> ..This publication is protected by copyright, and permission must be obtained from the publisher prior to any prohibited reproduction..

And there is a good reason for it. After all if everyone only copies a single item from it and puts it on Stack Overflow the financial gains of the author and the publisher may very well be strongly affected.

Fair use is a legal concept but probably differs from country to country and Stack Overflow operates worldwide. Also Stack Overflow Meta usually cannot offer legal advice. Better consult a lawyer.

My conclusion: You may violate the copyright. I would not do it and I advice you not to copy even a single item from that book or if you have done, retract your contribution soon.

Alternative: Describe the issue with your own words, present your own solution (which of course may be similar). In the end you may present the book (just the title and author, not even a link to Amazon (that would only be advertisement for Amazon)) as source of inspiration.

Comment: Fair Use is a [long-standing doctrine in US copyright law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), which I think is the only jurisdiction that counts here because the site is based in the US. It is very likely safe to quote portions from copyrighted works as long as you conform with the US version of Fair Use.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I didn't say fair use doesn't play a role. Please see the [comment of apsillers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334372/how-much-can-i-quote-a-book/334601?noredirect=1#comment394654_334372) above and links therein to find that "fair use" has it's limits. Typically we give not legal advice here. If you ask me, copying half a page containing the gist of an item is quite pronouncedly outside of fair use. Personally, I wouldn't have done that and I do not advice to do that. But please consult a lawyer, if you want to know exactly.

Comment: That said, I do generally suspect (as a non-lawyer) that the positive fair use factors of (1) the educational context of Stack Overflow and (2) the brevity of a short passage will generally serve to massively outweigh any negative factors in most cases in at least English-speaking jurisdictions.

Comment: @apsillers I strongly doubt the massive outweighing. After all, if you reproduce protected content item by item (just checked, there are 80 items in the book but still) at some point there is no need in buying it anymore. And especially in a case where it would be so simple to formulate the issues with your own words and circumvent the whole problem. It may be a violation of copyright, but them I'm not a lawyer and probably not many of us are, that's why these discussions do not get very far usually.