# How much can be quoted before it is considered plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Today I saw a answer that quoted an entire article in an answer by posting the article as an image in a quote block. The user also provided attribution.

Now ignoring that the content is an image and looking at it just from a plagiarism perspective is this allowed?
Do we have to check and see how the article is licensed or do we just have a prohibition of quoting an entire work no matter what it is published under?

If this is not allowed how should it be handled?  I can provide a link if necessary but I wanted to avoid the meta effect if possible.

I did find [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334372/how-much-can-i-quote-a-book) but it doesn't really  answer my questions.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I did find [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334372/how-much-can-i-quote-a-book) but it really doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: From [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): **Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.**

Comment: @BhargavRao Awesome.  Didn't even know we had that in the help file.

Comment: Now I'm thinking of copying all the text from [this other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326/4099593) and provide a link at the end.

Comment: @NathanOliver: [And that's the problem.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GuideDangIt)

Comment: BR found a dupe though so I just closed it as it does answer my question.

Comment: There's a little bit of confusion here. "The user also provided attribution." Providing attribution means that it's not plagiarism. Plagiarism is when you use someone else's work without saying it's someone else's. That still doesn't mean this is acceptable, of course. "Do we have to check and see how the article is licensed" If the quotation isn't marked as a quotation and isn't given attribution, it _is_ plagiarism regardless of whether the material is licensed for reuse. You can plagiarize public domain material.