# Is it okay to quote from ISO standards?

Tags: discussion, legal

This came to my mind when writing [Which object declarations in C cause storage to be reserved (i.e. are definitions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694056/which-object-declarations-in-c-cause-storage-to-be-reserved-i-e-are-definition), and there are a lot of other questions and answers in which people quote from ISO standards.

Sometimes it's suitable or even necessary to quote from ISO standards (e.g. from ISO/IEC 9899:2011 in a lot of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer related questions).  The copyright notice contains the half sentence "No part of this publication may be reproduced in any form".  I know that fair use allows some amount of citation.  But where are the limits?

Comment: related/ dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334372/how-much-can-i-quote-a-book.  Also if it weren't fine I think we would have heard about  years ago.

Comment: "But where are the limits?" Legally speaking, this can only be answered by someone suing someone and a court making a ruling, as Fair Use is an affirmative defense.  People can only guess at what they expect would happen based on a set of subjective guidelines (even though in practice certain cases are about as clear cut as it gets).

Comment: You may want to read http://www.isrm.gov.mk/en/images/upload/Direktivi%20i%20pravilnici/28.iso_policy_for_the_protection_of_iso_s_intellectual_property.pdf

Comment: Clarification: most quotes in the C and C++ language-lawyer answers are not from ISO standards, but from drafts of ISO standards and often indicated as such. The drafts do not contain this copyright notice and are as far as I know not owned by ISO. (This doesn't automatically mean copying is allowed and so doesn't substantially change the answer.)

Answer (score 20):

I think the short answer is that ISO lawyers aren’t ever going to come after you for quoting some short excerpt from an ISO standard in a Stack Overflow answer. So in practice, it’s effectively OK.

*Officially* though, I think all ISO standards have a boilerplate copyright/license statement that reads:

> All rights reserved. Unless otherwise specified, no part of this
>   publication may be reproduced or utilized in any form or by any means,
>   electronic or mechanical, including photocopying and microfilm,
>   without permission in writing from either ISO at the address below or
>   ISO's member body in the country of the requester.

So as far as what they are trying to assert there (*”no part of this publication may be reproduced or utilized in any form or by any means”) it’s not strictly OK to even quote short excerpts from them.

So I think the official ISO position on quoting anything from their standards is essentially that in all cases you’re supposed to write to them and ask. Which of course is ridiculous for something like the case of citing some language from a standard in an answer you post to Stack Overflow. But as far as I can see, ISO doesn’t really acknowledge the possibility of such cases.

Instead, the ISO basically seems consistent in taking a hard line on use of anything they assert a copyright on. [The copyright statement for their web site](https://www.iso.org/privacy-and-copyright.html) is this:

> All content on ISO Online is copyright protected. The copyright is owned by ISO. Any use of the content, including copying of it in whole or in part, for example to another Internet site, is prohibited and would require written permission from ISO.

So I think that’s another data point which indicates that as far as your question *“Is it okay to quote from ISO standards?”*, an ISO lawyer would say *No, it’s not OK.*

However that doesn’t mean it’s not OK, because in practice. copyright enforcement in a lot of countries provides for individual rights for limited use of material no  matter how much of a hard line the rights holders try to assert over the material.

(But as far as fair use, I think “fair use” itself as a term is mostly a US-specific thing and fair use isn’t an internationally recognized right. Some countries basically don’t recognize it as a right at all.)

Comment: Given that Stack Overflow is based/hosted in the United States, I would expect that [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) applies to all content here. As such, I would say that fair use meets the "otherwise specified" portion of the "unless otherwise specified" clause of the license statement. Then again, I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @CodyGray the states (not the states within the US) challenge this and usually represent that if a website is available in a country, then the website must abide by that country's law. This is why Google, Facebook, Microsoft - they all face lawsuits within the EU.

Comment: @Shadow I think there are many, many nuances in those cases that you are overlooking, such as data storage within those jurisdictions.

Comment: @Dan I think you are overlooking the individual states' desire to control multinational firms :) http://fortune.com/2016/02/15/facebook-loses-another-jurisdiction-fight-in-europe/ - French courts say they have jurisdiction over Facebook because otherwise it would nearly be impossible for a French citizen to sue Facebook. The linked article cites several other cases as well, where courts in various states confirmed they had jurisdiction over a company simply because it has operations in that country or just because its services are also sold in that country.

Comment: Btw, the US does the same the other way around.

Comment: @CodyGray "The laws of Switzerland shall govern all matters concerning ISO Intellectual Property . Any dispute bet ween two or more ISO members shall be brought  initially  to  the  attention  of  the Secretary-General, who will work with the parties with a view to reaching a settlement. If, and to the extent that, any such dispute is not settled, it will be referred to mediation followed by arbitration. The parties 
to the dispute shall at all times effectively and in good faith endeavour to reach a settlement." ISO/GEN 9:2007

Comment: Swiss copyright law says: "Published works may be quoted, but only if and as far as the quotation serves as a reference or illustration and the source of the quotation is designated, including the eventual name of the author." (*Switzerland Federal Law on Copyright and Neighbouring Rights*, October 9, 1992, Art. 25.)

Comment: @Shadow All `.dk` domains are legally considered Danish territory, just like Jylland, Sjælland or any physical part of Denmark. This is to make sure that anything that's available through a `.dk` domain is subject to Danish law.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the US, you are entitled to use (short) excerpts from any copyrighted document, as long as you cite your sources, under the fair-use doctrine, provided you are doing so for non-commercial purposes only. It is on you to assert fair use, however, should the copyright holder object to your usage.

Canada has a fair-dealing concept which is even less robust than American fair use, but I can't think of any other countries which have anything similar to fair use (maybe someone could offer some enlightenment on this front?), unfortunately.

Comment: [This document](http://ccarts.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/FairUseandFairDealinginForeignCountries.pdf) claims to summarize "fair use" laws in a variety of countries. I cannot, obviously, vouch for its legal accuracy.

Comment: Fair use doesn't allow for *any* short excepts to be used in a non-commercial setting.  It's more complex than that.  There are multiple factors that together all form a set of guidelines as to whether or not something is fair use.  Length is one *factor*.  Note that SO is a commercial product, so posting content here *is* using it commercially (not that that alone excludes something from being fair use).